# Cannot use KILL to kill your own process

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have SQL Server database which I want to delete using

```
DROP DATABASE <database-Name>
```

But I receive this error:

Cannot drop database "Database-Name" because it is currently in use.

To solve the issue I called sp_who so I can see spid of the database which is in use.

Then I tried to kill it using :

```
KILL <spid>
```

But I see this error: Cannot use KILL to kill your own process.
I use SQL SERVER Management Studio to run the commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot kill your own session and cannot drop a database in use. Since the whole story tells you try to drop the database your session is currently using you can change the database used by your session and then drop the database.

```
USE master; -- or any other database not named <database name>
DROP DATABASE <database name>;
```